# compare response.text and string failed in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a mission to filter response whether it's a normal response or not.

I should log the response if response.text is not`'<Br>No match<br>OK!!'`.

```py
if not response.text == '<Br>No match<br>OK!!':
    logger.info('ERROR!!')
```

But I still can check the error message in log file which is `'<Br>No match<br>OK!!'`

I fixed my code as bellow but It doesn't work.

```
if not str(response.text) == '<Br>No match<br>OK!!':
    logger.info('ERROR!!')
```

There was the other message in response.text that encoded with **ISO-8859-1**. Centain text in the log was broken so I could get the right text like `normalize('NFC', msg).encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('cp949').`

```
u'hello' == 'hello'.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('cp949')  # True
```

Is there any problem with my code? Or what should I check more? please help me.